# Dart/Flutter. elements jump in Row if the child widget changes size

Tags: flutter, dart, row, padding

Row elements should change their padding depending on which element is selected. I've tried different options with padding, changed it in every way, but it's always the same option - AnimatedContainer always jumps, changes position, and does not stay in one place. How can this be corrected?

`

```
Positioned(
      bottom: 100,
      left: 52,
      child: Row(
        // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          for (int i = 0; i <= widget.planets.length - 1; i++)
            Builder(
              builder: (context) {
                final isSelected = selectedIndex == i;
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedIndex = i;
                    });
                    widget.getIndex(i);
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: i == 0
                          ? 0
                          : isSelected
                              ? 16.0
                              : 26.0,
                    ),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 130,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: AnimatedContainer(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              curve: Curves.decelerate,
                              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                              width: isSelected ? 80 : 40,
                              height: isSelected ? 80 : 40,
                              child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                widget.planets[i].imageSvg,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                widget.planets[i].points,
                                style: widget.planets[i].isAchieved
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(height: 4),
                              Text(
                                widget.planets[i].title,
                                style: SRTypo.tabBarMediumWhite,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

`

It is necessary that the indentation of the elements in the Row be the same, regardless of which element is selected